# How to find the course of multiple php-cgi process?

Tags: php

I have a small wordpress blog on local zend server. Recently I felt my PC slow down and  I found a lot of php-cgi.exe are running. Some said cron job is the course but I don't have any plugin running cron job. Where can I go to check the log of php-cig process?